# how to trim/edit MESSAGE field of opentelemetry log sent to google cloud logging?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-storage, open-telemetry

so below is the log that i am getting in the google cloud logging after using opentelemetry observiq-otel-collector

{
"insertId": "somevalue",
"jsonPayload": {
"_CMDLINE": "somevalue",
"_UID": "somevalue",
"_BOOT_ID": "somevalue",
"SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER": "somevalue",
"_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID": "somevalue",
"_SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT": "somevalue-somevalue.somevalue",
"_MACHINE_ID": "somevalue",
"_AUDIT_LOGINUID": "somevalue",
"_PID": "somevalue",
"_EXE": "/usr/bin/python3.8",
"_GID": "somevalue",
"_STREAM_ID": "somevalue",
"__CURSOR": "somevalue",
"MESSAGE": "2023-09-14 16:32:48,315|INFO|somefile.py|MAIN-MESSAGE THAT I WANT|813",
"_TRANSPORT": "stdout",
"_HOSTNAME": "somevalue",
"_SYSTEMD_CGROUP": "somevalue",
"_SYSTEMD_USER_SLICE": "-.slice",
"PRIORITY": "6",
"__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP": "somevalue",
"_CAP_EFFECTIVE": "0",
"_SELINUX_CONTEXT": "unconfined\n",
"_AUDIT_SESSION": "2",
"_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "somevalue",
"_SYSTEMD_SLICE": "somevalue",
"_COMM": "somevalue",
"_SYSTEMD_OWNER_UID": "somevalue"
},
"resource": {
"type": "generic_node",
"labels": {
"project_id": "somevalue",
"node_id": "somevalue",
"namespace": "",
"location": "somevalue"
}
},
"timestamp": "somevalue",
"labels": {
"devicetype": "somevalue",
"deviceid": "somevalue"
},
"logName": somevalue",
"receiveTimestamp": "somevalue"
}

and my config.yaml of observiq-otel-collector is

receivers:
journald:
units:
- "*"
priority: info
start_at: end
grep: "somevalue"
matches:
- SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER: "somevalue"
journald/error:
units:
- "*"
priority: err
start_at: end
grep: "somevalue"
processors:
attributes:
actions:
- key: somevalue
value: somevalue-somevalue-somevalue-somevalue
action: upsert
- key: somevalue
value: "somevalue somevalue"
action: upsert
exporters:
googlecloud:
project: somevalue-somevalue
credentials_file: /opt/observiq-otel-collector/logging_access_keys.json
log:
default_log_name: st-scan-logs
# bucket: "jctltest"

googlecloud/errors:
project: somevalue-somevalue
credentials_file: /opt/observiq-otel-collector/logging_access_keys.json
log:
default_log_name: st-error-logs

service:
pipelines:
logs:
receivers: [journald]
processors: [attributes]
exporters: [googlecloud]
logs/errors:
receivers: [journald/error]
processors: [attributes]
exporters: [googlecloud/errors]

now i want the message to be "MESSAGE": "MAIN-MESSAGE THAT I WANT" instead of "MESSAGE": "2023-09-14 16:32:48,315|INFO|somefile.py|MAIN-MESSAGE THAT I WANT|813",

how can i change my config.yaml to achive this?

suggest me the new config.yaml of observiq-otel-collector